# What is the difference between muscle tension and muscle tightness?

Tags: terminology, muscles

Is there any difference between muscle *tension* and muscle *tightness*?

I want to study the relation between forearm muscles tightness/tension and tendinopathy (specifically, medial and lateral epicondylopathy) in humans. In that context, I wanted to understand whether muscle tension and muscle tightness are synonymous, and if not what the difference is.

Comment: In what context do you mean? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: @kmm Thanks for the comment. I want to study the relation between forarm muscles tightness/tension and tendinopathy (specifically, medial and lateral epicondylopathy) in humans. In that context, I wanted to understand whether muscle tension and muscle tightness are synonymous, and if not what the difference is.